# Position of element changes after changing left and top value from pixel to percentage

Tags: jquery, html, jquery-ui-droppable

I am using [jQuery Droppable](http://api.jqueryui.com/droppable/) and want to save the coordinates in percentage value. So I have written the code to covert the Pixel value to percentage.

But I marked while its in (0,0) position percentage value comes perfect but as I move the element to Downward of the parent element percentage value of TOP decreasing and percentage value of Left Increasing. So at the bottom left corner element has around 12% of increased left percentage and 8% decreased top percentage.

Update : The percentage value what I get after drag and drop, when I put that percentage value to the elements style it shifts the element towards top and right. That means top percentage value decreasing and left percentage value increasing.

I cant find the reason why percentage value varies while the calculation remains same. Here is the code,

```
jQuery("#editor").droppable({
    drop: function( event, ui ) {

        var pos = ui.draggable.offset();
        var dPos = $(this).offset();

        // Pixxel value of positions
        var elementTopPosition = pos.top - dPos.top;
        var elementLeftPosition = pos.left - dPos.left;

        // Getting parent element height and width
        var parentWidth = jQuery("#editor").width();
        var ParentHeight = jQuery("#editor").height();

        // Coverting to percentage
        var topInPercentage = ( 100 * elementTopPosition ) / ParentHeight;
        var leftInPercentage = ( 100 * elementLeftPosition ) / parentWidth;

    }
});
```

While I save an element position with percentage value : 
http://www.awesomescreenshot.com/image/436490/b1b1c6c910b0f68a4199c8f67684ac56

When I output that element position  with saved percentage value :
http://www.awesomescreenshot.com/image/436526/12d4b0778240646285c6fdd10e61bd2f

**Live Example** ([fiddle if you prefer](https://jsfiddle.net/kr64c5Lf/1/)):

```js
$("#draggable").draggable();

jQuery("#droppable").droppable({
    drop: function (event, ui) {

        debugger;

        var pos = ui.draggable.offset();
        var dPos = $(this).offset();

        // Pixxel value of positions
        var elementTopPosition = pos.top - dPos.top;
        var elementLeftPosition = pos.left - dPos.left;

        // Getting parent element height and width
        var parentWidth = jQuery("#droppable").width();
        var ParentHeight = jQuery("#droppable").height();

        // Coverting to percentage
        var topInPercentage = (100 * elementTopPosition) / ParentHeight;
        var leftInPercentage = (100 * elementLeftPosition) / parentWidth;
        
        $("#draggable").css({top: topInPercentage + '%', left: leftInPercentage + '%'});

    }
});
```

```css
#draggable {
    width: 100px;
    padding: 2px 5px;
    cursor: pointer;
    color: #fff;
    position: absolute;
}
#droppable {
    position: relative;
    width: 200px;
    height: 200px;
    background: #999;
    color: #fff;
    padding: 10px;
}
```

```html
<div id="droppable">
    <div id="draggable">Element</div>
</div>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
```

So, try moving the element in between its parent, in each move I am capturing the left top pixel value and convert it to Percentage and then apply that percentage value gain to that element. But it differs from the original postion value.

Comment: @Dipak Have a look at [this code](https://jsfiddle.net/kr64c5Lf/), the top % increases when it is dragged downwards. Can you point out the problem in there? Update the code to recreate your issue and provide a link to it if necessary.

Comment: Sorry folks, have to do a Stack course I think.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want `outerWidth`/`outerHeight` rather than `width`/`height`:

```js
$("#draggable").draggable();

jQuery("#droppable").droppable({
    drop: function (event, ui) {

        debugger;

        var pos = ui.draggable.offset();
        var dPos = $(this).offset();

        // Pixxel value of positions
        var elementTopPosition = pos.top - dPos.top;
        var elementLeftPosition = pos.left - dPos.left;

        // Getting parent element height and width
        var parentWidth = jQuery("#droppable").outerWidth();   // <=== Here
        var ParentHeight = jQuery("#droppable").outerHeight(); // <===

        // Coverting to percentage
        var topInPercentage = (100 * elementTopPosition) / ParentHeight;
        var leftInPercentage = (100 * elementLeftPosition) / parentWidth;
        
        $("#draggable").css({top: topInPercentage + '%', left: leftInPercentage + '%'});

    }
});
```

```css
#draggable {
    width: 100px;
    padding: 2px 5px;
    cursor: pointer;
    color: #fff;
    position: absolute;
}
#droppable {
    position: relative;
    width: 200px;
    height: 200px;
    background: #999;
    color: #fff;
    padding: 10px;
}
```

```html
<div id="droppable">
    <div id="draggable">Element</div>
</div>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
```